# How to trigger a function on horizontal scroll of a component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a horizontal scroller, which can be controlled both ways,

1. By arrows
2. By a mouse or touch scroll

Both are done, but there is one problem which I am trying to achieve but couldn't understand how to do it.

> **I want to trigger a function on horizontal scroll so that I can hide and unhide the arrow button by scrolling with mouse and touch scroll too. How can I do that? or any other way?**

[horizontal Scroller](https://codesandbox.io/s/hscroll-1oril?file=/src/cards.js), here is the code of horizontal scroller, which I have achieved yet

Any type of help will be appreciated.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have achieved this is using the onScroll synthetic event from React [onScroll](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#ui-events) to hide the arrows when scrolling and then calling a setTimeout when to display the arrows when the scrolling stops.

Example here: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hscroll-forked-6fezq?file=/src/cards.js)

Answer (score 0):

The final code of the horizontal scroller is here,  [Horizontal Scroller](https://codesandbox.io/s/hscroll-1oril?file=/src/cards.js)